# Pyinstaller compiled executable fails with 139 exit code

Tags: python, exec, executable, pyinstaller

I have a Python 3 script that works well on my Linux Debian machine.
I compiled it with Pyinstaller, (since only Python2.7 is installed on the server) and the generated executable is working fine on my machine as well.
Then I copied the generated folder to a Linux server and tried to invoke it with the following PHP command:

```
exec(dirname(__FILE__) . "/solve --state $state 2>&1", $response, $r);
```

The $r variable contains the 139 exit code. I found out that this means some fragmentation error. I ran the "chmod 0764" command on the executable, but the problem still persists.

Does anyone have any idea how could I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that FileZilla didn't recognize the Linux executable file as an executable and presumably copied it to the server as a text file. I uploaded it with another FTP client and now it's working fine.